# In Xcode macOS deployment target is 10.15 but on launch, app requires macOS 11.3

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, macos-catalina, target-platform

*Xcode 12.5.1 · macOS 12.0 Beta 6*

I have been upgrading a macOS app written by someone else, which has **always worked correctly on macOS 10.15 Catalina**.

Having finished the upgrades, I find that **it no longer launches on Catalina**:

[image]

However, I have not changed the macOS Deployment Target, which is still 10.15:

[image]

I don't know what would cause the requirement for macOS 11.3 — **every modification to the program was done using capabilities that were present in the previous version**.

**I did not modify any build parameters** — I only changed the code.

**I have updated Xcode since the previous release.**

I have done quite a lot of Googling, but I have not been able to find anything. The relevant search terms all turn up results about Xcode versions.

Any pointers in looking for an answer, or even just a direction to investigate, would be very helpful.

Comment: Same pic location -> select target Svija sync -> choose deployment target there. Verify Info.plist of packaged application -> look for key minimum os

Comment: Just for future - first picture is project settings aka global settings for each target (yes you can have more than one). Inside target you can override the global settings with a custom ones.

Comment: Do not modify your question to include the answer. If you have an answer to your own question, give it as an Answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Marek H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648673/marek-h) pointed out that I needed to specify a Deployment Target for the **target app** as well as for the project. Since the field had previously been empty, I didn't notice it:

[image]

I entered the correct Deployment Target and the problem was solved:

[image]